# StackOverflowError (java fx)

Tags: java, javafx, runtime, javafx-8, stack-overflow

I am writing a code with a class for drawing a line and another class to display the line. The point of the class is for me to easily write multiple lines and make my code a bit more organized. But for some reason, I am getting a StackOverflow error whenever I run it. I am unsure on why this is happening. it also gives me a RunTimeException and a lot of different error messages like "Exception in application start method". I am unsure on what those are supposed to mean.

This is the error messages it gives me:

```
    Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:873)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Line.<init>(Main.java:133)
    at Line.<init>(Main.java:133)
    at Line.<init>(Main.java:133) //this just repeats a bunch of times
Exception running application Main
```

This is the code:

```
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

class Line{

    public Line line;

    public Line(int x1,  int y1, int x2, int y2){

        Line line = new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    public void setFill(Paint p) {
        line.setFill(p);
    }

}

public class Main extends Application {
    private Pane root;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        root = new Pane();

        Line line1 = new Line(250,250,450,450);

        root.getChildren().addAll((Collection<? extends Node>) line1);
        line1.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Empty");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.launch(args);
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you post the full text of the error? All of the lines.  It would help us understand what is happening.

Comment: Which line is 133 in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because this never ends.

```
public Line(int x1,  int y1, int x2, int y2){

        Line line = new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
```

While creating a new object, you are calling the constructor. And within it, it's creating an object, which leads to calling constructor again and so on.

So do this instead:

```
class Line{

    int x1,x2,y1,y2;

    public Line(int x1,  int y1, int x2, int y2){

        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

}
```

You don't need to create `setFill()` function as it's imported. Simply use the function.

Comment: Thanks! But I now have a new issue, for the setFill method it says that the line symbol cannot be resolved

Comment: It's the same mistake again. that method is calling itself again(recursive). It's doing nothing else. Can you tell me what it's supposed to do?

Comment: You can remove that, you don't need to create `setFill()` function as it's imported. Simply use the function.

Comment: @ShawnHawkins You trying to do `line.setFill(...)` makes me think you're trying to use a `javafx.scene.shape.Line`. But your own class is named `Line`. See the conflict? Either rename your class or use the fully qualified name of `javafx.scene.shape.Line` everywhere you use it.

Comment: @ShawnHawkins This should be failing too: `root.getChildren().addAll((Collection<? extends Node>) line1);`. Not only is `line1` not a `java.util.Collection` but it's not even a `javafx.scene.Node`. May I ask why you defined your own `Line` class? Why not just use `javafx.scene.shape.Line`?

Comment: @sittsering "_You don't need to create_ `setFill()` _function as it's imported. Simply use the function_" – Not sure I understand what you're trying to say here. Instance methods can't be imported.

Comment: @Slaw this is for my homework assignment, the assignment states it should be in OOP style coding which is why I put it like that (I am new to javaFX and OOP so feel free to ask any questions to help clarify my questions)

Comment: @ShawnHawkins You're making some mistakes on the JavaFX side. The structure of JavaFX has a `Window` (where `Stage` is one implementation) as the top-level container. Then that `Window` has a `Scene`. The `Scene` has a root which is an instance of `Parent`. From there the scene graph is made up of implementations of `Node` (note that `Parent` inherits from `Node`). So essentially everything that can be added to the GUI must be a `Node`. Your `Line` is not a `Node`. Given you want a model class, and that `javafx.scene.shape.Line` exists, I strongly suggest you rename your `Line` class.

Comment: You would then create a `javafx.scene.shape.Line` (which inherits from `Node`) _from_ an instance of your model class by using the data of the model class to set the appropriate properties of the JavaFX `Line` object.